# Show one row at a time from access database using ASP Classic

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I need help with my asp project,

There is a loop in my page where only one row from a table is looping through the whole page, instead i want to show only one row then i want to add a button / link that loads 2nd row then 3rd row, the 4th row and on wards.

How can i achieve this?

Here is my code

```
<%
if session("usr")="" then
response.Redirect("authentication.asp")
end if

Set Rs=con.execute("select * from Std_Profile where uid=" & session("usr") & "")

Dim ccode
ccode=Rs("Class_Code")

Set RSlecture=con.execute("select * from eva_lecture where Class_Code='"& ccode &"' ")
Set RSques=con.execute("select * from eva_ques ")


Dim PageLen,PageNo,TotalRecord,TotalPage,No,intID
PageLen = 1 
PageNo = Request.QueryString("Page")
if PageNo = "" Then PageNo = 1
TotalRecord = RSlecture.RecordCount
RSlecture.PageSize = PageLen
TotalPage = RSlecture.PageCount
RSlecture.AbsolutePage = PageNo


%>

<div class="activity">

<%
        No=1
        Do While Not RSlecture.EOF and No <= PageLen
%>
<h3><strong>Q#<% Response.Write(RSques("ques_no"))%> : <% Response.Write(RSques("ques"))%></strong></h3>
<br />
<table width="837" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr align="center">
<td width="79" bgcolor="#6699CC"><strong>Subject</strong></td>
<td width="74" bgcolor="#6699CC"><strong>Teacher</strong></td>
<td width="120" bgcolor="#6699CC"><strong>Option #1</strong></td>
<td width="120" bgcolor="#6699CC"><strong>Option #2</strong></td>
<td width="120" bgcolor="#6699CC"><strong>Option #3</strong></td>
<td width="120" bgcolor="#6699CC"><strong>Option #4</strong></td>
</tr>
</table>

<% 'While Not RSlecture.EOF %>

<table width="837" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr align="center">
<td width="79"><% Response.Write(RSlecture("subject"))%></td>
<td width="74"><% Response.Write(RSlecture("teacher"))%></td>
<td width="120"><% Response.Write(RSques("opt1"))%></td>
<td width="120"><% Response.Write(RSques("opt2"))%></td>
<td width="120"><% Response.Write(RSques("opt3"))%></td>
<td width="120"><% Response.Write(RSques("opt4"))%></td>
</tr>
</table>

<%
        No = No + 1
        RSlecture.MoveNext
        Loop
%>

Total : <%=TotalRecord%> Records.  Page <%=PageNo%> (All Page <%=TotalPage%>)
    <% IF Cint(PageNo) > 1 then %>
    <a href="<%=Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")%>?Page=1"><< First</a> 
    <a href="<%=Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")%>?Page=<%=PageNo-1%>">< Back</a>
    <% End IF%>
    <% IF Cint(PageNo) < TotalPage Then %>
    <a href="<%=Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")%>?Page=<%=PageNo+1%>">Next ></a> 
    <a href="<%=Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")%>?Page=<%=TotalPage%>">Last >></a>
    <% End IF%>
    <br>
    Go to
    <% For intID = 1 To TotalPage%>
    <% if intID = Cint(PageNo) Then%>
    <b><%=intID%></b>
    <%Else%>
    <a href="<%=Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")%>?Page=<%=intID%>"><%=intID%></a>
    <%End IF%>
    <%Next%>

<div>
```

it returns

**Error Type:
ADODB.Recordset (0x800A0CB3)
Current Recordset does not support bookmarks. This may be a limitation of the provider or of the selected cursortype.**

Comment: Look into term called recordset paging. Try it yourself. If you still get stuck edit your post with what you tried and we'll try to guide you through.

Comment: thanks, let me try that...

Comment: @ShadowWizard i have tried the paging function but it returns a CursorType error :(

Comment: What function? Like I said, post your efforts as edit to the question.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to update my question. please check now

Comment: Better now, see my answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard paging is working fine now, using your provided code. but i have to sort some issues with loop. thank you for your help, i really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your order of commands is wrong. Try this:

```vbs
Set RSques=con.execute("select * from eva_ques ")

Dim PageLen, PageNo, TotalRecord, TotalPage, No, intID

PageLen = 1 
PageNo = Request.QueryString("Page")
if PageNo = "" Then PageNo = 1

Set RSlecture = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RSlecture.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient
RSlecture.Open "select * from eva_lecture where Class_Code='"& ccode &"' ", con

RSlecture.PageSize = PageLen
RSlecture.AbsolutePage = PageNo

TotalRecord = RSlecture.RecordCount
TotalPage = RSlecture.PageCount
```

Comment: if you don't mind looking into this Q: too 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081919/how-to-loop-from-two-tables